# Removing identifiable metadata from azw3

Tags: send-to-kindle, azw

Amazon's "Send to Kindle by E-mail" service lets me write a DOCX file, etc. then send it to my Kindle. It automatically converts the sent file into AZW3. But during the process they add identifiable information to that AZW3.

Does it contain anything else other than e-mail address and is there a simple way to remove the identifiable info, just like you can remove such info [from other file formats](https://www.siam.org/Publications/Journals/Related/Journal-Policies/Detail/protecting-referee-personal-information)?

Note I'm not talking about DRM, just identifiable metadata.

[image: The blue part has the username's e-mail address]
(I've pixalated the blue highlight which has the username's e-mail address)

Comment: This has aspects of social DRM.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the AZW3 format with the [calibre editor](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/edit.html).

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you elaborate on this a bit? While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](/help/deleted-answers).